# How do I use Powershell to set Delegate permission on a mailbox?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, powershell, exchange-2010

When I add a user to Outlook delegation, using this method

[image]

I see them in the following powershell command

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-CalendarProcessing aaaa| fl


AutomateProcessing                  : AutoUpdate
AllowConflicts                      : False
BookingWindowInDays                 : 180
MaximumDurationInMinutes            : 1440
AllowRecurringMeetings              : True
EnforceSchedulingHorizon            : True
ScheduleOnlyDuringWorkHours         : False
ConflictPercentageAllowed           : 0
MaximumConflictInstances            : 0
ForwardRequestsToDelegates          : True
DeleteAttachments                   : True
DeleteComments                      : True
RemovePrivateProperty               : True
DeleteSubject                       : True
AddOrganizerToSubject               : True
DeleteNonCalendarItems              : True
TentativePendingApproval            : True
EnableResponseDetails               : True
OrganizerInfo                       : True
ResourceDelegates                   : {asdf.com/New York/NY Users/bbbb, bbbb}
RequestOutOfPolicy                  : {}
AllRequestOutOfPolicy               : False
BookInPolicy                        : {}
AllBookInPolicy                     : True
RequestInPolicy                     : {}
AllRequestInPolicy                  : False
AddAdditionalResponse               : False
AdditionalResponse                  :
RemoveOldMeetingMessages            : True
AddNewRequestsTentatively           : True
ProcessExternalMeetingMessages      : False
RemoveForwardedMeetingNotifications : False
```

However when I set the user as a delegate, I get the following error:

```
set-CalendarProcessing ifischer -ResourceDelegates {"aaa.com/New York/NY Users/bbb,bbb"}
ResourceDelegates can only be enabled on resource mailboxes.
```

Answer (score 1):

This response is a little late, I apologize.

The powershell cmdlet you're using there (Set-CalendarProcessing) is only for 'Resource' mailboxes. This refers to objects like rooms, company cars, projectors, and other things that your organization use by booking time on a calendar.

This particular Exchange object type has a special calendar assistant available that can either automatically accept or reject calendar requests that are sent to it, or you can set a delegate. The naming here is misleading, since delegate is used elsewhere in the Exchange world to mean something else.

The error you recieved is indicating that the mailbox you're trying to run this cmdlet against is not a resource type, so it doesn't have the special calendar attendant, and therefore cannot have a delegate.

As far as I know, the only way to set the type of delegate you're trying to set is by doing it manually through the Outlook desktop client (like your screenshot shows).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can can complete this with the following command:

```
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity user1@domian:\calendar -user user2@domian -SharingPermission Delegate -AccessRights Editor
```

Remember to use `Set-MailboxFolderPermission` instead of `Add-MailboxFolderPermission` if they already have Access Rights to the mailbox.